# How to format a JSON date without GMT

Tags: jquery, json

I want to format a JSON date.I search and I found this link. [Json Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date) When I use @Roy's ans mention in above question I get a result in format:

```
Mon Jul 16 2012 14:10:42 GMT+0545 (Nepal Standard Time)
```

but I want a result in format:

```
Mon Jul 16 2012 14:10:42
```

How can I avoid unnecessary part to get desire result.Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to apply a format in raw data?

Comment: `Mon Jul 16 2012 14:10:42` is meaningless without timezone

Comment: @Esailija  yap.I want because it is using in local site so time zone is not important.

Comment: Why not do a `.toString()` and some string manipulation? Or use a combination of methods listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dt = new Date().toString();
console.log(dt); // Mon Jul 16 2012 15:21:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
dt = dt.substr(0, dt.indexOf('GMT'));
console.log(dt); // Mon Jul 16 2012 15:21:09
```

From the looks of it, this seems to be what you want....